# removeAllObservers observer not removed

Tags: firebase

Having an issue removing an observer; the event appears to fire even after removeAllObservers

Here's the data structure

```
listOfItems
    Item 1
        Key:Value
    Item 2
        Key:Value
```

Initially, listOfItems is being observed

```
[refToListOfItems observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    NSLog(@"responding to value change in the list of items");
}];
```

but at some point, I want to update Item 1 Key:Value pair without being observed, so I remove the observer from Item 1

[refToItem1 removeAllObservers];

then proceed to update the dictionary of Item 1

```
NSDictionary *testData = @{
                           @"newKey": @"newValue"
                           };

[refToItem1 updateChildValues:testData];
```

But the observer event is still fired for the refToItem1 element.

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
It appears that observing an object can only be removed if it's implicitly set on that object. i.e. if you set an observing on an object, that observation can be removed. But it cannot be removed on child objects of the first object being observed?

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue myself, if I'm understanding you correctly.  Storing `refToItem1` in an iVar won't work because it's overwritten each time in the loop.

My solution was to store child Firebase references in an array, then loop through that array when I want to remove all of the observers.

e.g.

```
self.parentRef = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"url"];

NSMutableArray *childObservers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[self.parentRef observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {
    Firebase *childRef = [ref childByAppendingPath...];

    [childObservers addObject:childRef];

    [ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *childSnapshot) {
         ... observations
    }];
}];
```

Then later to remove the observers:

```
- (void)stopObserving { 
   [self.parentRef removeAllObservers];

   for (Firebase *ref in self.childObservers) {
       [ref removeAllObservers];
   }
}
```